# Having trouble transfering private keys from Bitcoin Core to Electrum, for want of not having to wait for sync

Tags: electrum, import, sweep

This morning, I purchased some bitcoin for the first time on CEX.IO, and soon withdrew it to the Bitcoin Core wallet I had set up. What I did not realise was that I would have to download the blockchain data and store it, which is proving painfully slow on my lacklustre internet connection. I have since downloaded Electrum, obtained the private key from the Bitcoin core console, and imported this into my Electrum wallet. Although Electrum says it has imported, it does not read the correct public address that BC does, and my balance is still at zero. When I check the balance of the address online it still reads as it should. Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redo the import. Start via file > new/restore, enter a unique filename and click next to begin the process. This time prepend one of the following to the private key:

- p2wpkh: if the address in question begins with bc1
- p2wpkh-p2sh: if the address in question begins with 3

For example:

p2wpkh-p2sh:Ky9mddDtaqcLC1vv6egmgQpiZh8Lgh111LnJSyJENxJs3oW93bjD

You can also click on the info button on the private key entry step to see further examples.